# First steps in understanding ergodic theorems

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, ergodic-theory

I'm trying to understand ergodic theorems. I use the book written by [Peter Walters "An introduction to ergodic theorem"](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387951522).

I would like to ask what would one consider to be an *ergodic theorem for discrete time* and *ergodic theorem for continuous time*?

I also would like to know what was the first ergodic theorem? I would like to understand the proofs chronologically. Maybe there is a really simple paper of book containing those?

I would really appreciate any hints or tips.